# Como usar autocomplete do JQuery com C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Galera, estou tentando usar autocomplete do JQuery no C# a partir de um método que me trás uma lista de clientes do banco de dados (o banco de dados é o do NorthWind disponibilizado pela Microsoft), porém estou obtendo um erro que eu não consigo resolver fazem horas.

[image: Erro que eu obtenho no console do navegador depois de digitar uma letra no textbox]

Abaixo o código no back end e também no front end:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<Customer> GetAll(string nome)
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        List<Customer> customersList = new List<Customer>();
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ContactName LIKE @nome";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", "%" + nome + "%");
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Customer customer = new Customer();

                customer.CustermerID = dataReader["CustomerID"].ToString();
                customer.Name = dataReader["ContactName"].ToString();

                customersList.Add(customer);
            }

            return customersList;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Teste.aspx.cs" Inherits="JQueryAutocomplete.Teste" %>
```

```
<link type="text/css" href="Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SearchText();  
    });  
    function SearchText() {  
        $("#nomeTextBox").autocomplete({  
            source: function(request, response) {  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url: "Teste.aspx/GetAll",  
                    data: "{'nome':'" + document.getElementById('nomeTextBox').value + "'}",  
                    dataType: "json",  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        response(data.d);  
                    },  
                    error: function(result) {  
                        alert("No Match");  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        });  
    }  

</script>
```

Nome:

Comment: Me parece que seu problema não é nem no jQuery em si, mas em que o servidor não está autorizando a requisição (erro 401).

Comment: Ao invés de usar um `trow` pegue o texto da exceção dentro do `catch` e mostre para nós para que tenhamos uma ideia mais detalhada do que está acontecendo.

Comment: O programa não chega a cair no bloco 'catch'. O que acontece é que depois que carrego a aplicação e digito alguma letra no text box, ao invés de ele me mostrar a lista filtrada com esse determinado dígito, não acontece nada e no console aparece o erro 401. Mas eu não sei, porque está causando isso.  :(

Answer (score 0):

dentro de ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs mudar:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Para:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

Ou apenas comente a linha

Se as URLs amigáveis estiverem ativas deves fazer esta alteração

```
url: "Teste.aspx/GetAll",
```

Para:

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("Teste.aspx/GetAll") %>'
```

Espero que ajude.